# How to display data with ngfor but decide the property name at runtime

Tags: angular, runtime, ngfor

I have angular ngfor code where I am using an observable to display a list. However my issue is that I want to inject the name of the object property in the underlying array at runtime to display in the list.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would help to share some pseudo or sample code to better understand your issue.

Comment: Are you trying to decide which property to show at runtime or you want to change the property name inside the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your coming object or array of object's properties and change them what you want keep the property name like if you are getting this response from api :

```
persons = [{age : 32, name : "John"},{age:33,name : "Alex"}];
persons.map(item=>{
  item.fullName = item.name;
  delete item.name;
})
```

in your component.html you can show like this

```
 <li *ngFor="lelt person of persons">{{person.fullName}}</li>
```